# How do I define an environment depending on what the current URL looks like?

Tags: angularjs

I come from the server, and in the Laravel framework, we have a concept of 'environments'.

There's a `paths.php` file, and you can define an array like so:

```
$environments = [
    'local' => ['*.dev', 'http://localhost/*'],
    'staging' => ['staging.url.com']
]
```

Corresponding config files can then be made inside subfolders 'local' and 'staging' and stuff like database settings, etc., is pulled from there.

**Why do I want this?**

I'd like to auto detect the base URL to use depending on where I am:

```
angular
.module('myApp.services', [])
.value('homeURL', 'http://local.dev')
//.value('homeURL', 'http://server.com');
```

Then I can proceed to use `{{ homeURL }}` in various views of the app etc., Right now, I comment/uncomment the appropriate lines just before pushing to server, but would be nice if there was an easier way...

Comment: Uh oh. Just came across `window.location.hostname` in the MDN wiki... maybe this is the answer to what I need, not even an angular problem? Sorry for the ignorance if that is the case!

Comment: are you looking for angular's router? http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: I found `$location.host()`, which is exactly what I need =) don't know what to do with this question now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could use angular's `$location.host()` instead, which fits my needs perfectly.